# Enabling IK stretch in the IK Constraint does nothing?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

Enabling IK **stretch** in the **IK Constraint**S

[image]

**Stretch** in the **IK Constraint** does nothing?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution is to make the stretch value in

*BONE > INVERSE KINEMETICS > STRETCH*  to more than zero and not close to 1

**I set it to 0.1** As seen in Pitchipoy rig set up

[image]
[image]

It has to be done for each bone in the chain

[image]
[image]

Comment: "more than zero and not close to 1", why not close to 1? You need to write your reasoning behind it, even if it's "I have no idea why, it just works this way".